# Developing fast twitch muscles with small weights

Tags: muscle, strength, fiber

Or, do we have to use heavy weights for that?

Would isometric exercise be of any use? (theoretically I imagine that these don't have a top of force applied).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.  Could you please provide an example, or perhaps a hyperlink to relevant external resources?

Comment: Are you asking how to develop fast twitch muscles?

Comment: @ChristianConti-Vock: rewritten

Comment: @DeeV: yes, but I only have 1 kettlebell of 16 kg.

Answer (score 2):

Applying [Henneman’s size principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henneman%27s_size_principle), we can see that the body will not recruit fast-twitch muscle fibers to move small/light loads.  Muscle fibers are trained only by recruiting them.  So, you need (relatively) heavy weights to develop fast-twitch muscle fibers.  In this respect, a single kettlebell of 16 kg will be of limited use.  Isometric exercise will be of limited use, too, because it it difficult to quantify, and therefore unsuitable for progressive resistance training.